# error looping throught columns names pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops

So, I have a df where a question is answered in different columns:

```
          Main activity at work     Main activity at work .1    Main activity at work .2 ... Main activity at work .20
            
     0       machine operator             administrator                           null            cleaning
     1              null                       null                              accountant       cleaning 
     2           machine operator              null                                null           null
     3              null                  administrator                            null           cleaning
```

and so on. Each column have only one type of answer, where it applies.

Now, this things is simple, I want to do value_counts( ) for all the columns at once. So my desired output is:

```
main activity at work   
machine operator 20

main activity at work .1
administrator  14

main activity at work .2
accountant    10
```

and so on. My problem is with the column names. I used this code:

```
activity = pd.Series('Main activity at work  .'+ pd.Series(np.arange(1,21)).map(str))

for num in activity:

    print(df['activity'].value_counts(), '\n')
```

but i get this error message:

```
KeyError: 'activity'
```

What is the error or else, is there a better way to do it?

EDIT: "Main activity at work", "Main activity at work .1" and so on, are column names, so I don't have a single name for all of them. That was what my loop stood for in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `df['activity']`, which means you want the column 'activity'. When you write something in quotation marks it's a string not a variable. So that can not work. I did not test it but if you want to have a chance must write something like df[num]. But even if that should work here is a more practicle way: Use the [itmes()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iteritems.html) method to iterate through the columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'species': ['bear', 'bear', 'marsupial'],
                       'population': [1864, 22000, 80000]},
                      )
dict = {}
for label, content in df.items():
    series = content.value_counts()
    dict[label] = series  
    print(series)
```

For littlebit more understanding. The variable label is the column name and content is its content as pandas series. I don't know if you only need to print the output, so i additional used a dictionary to store the output.

Comment: The loop was to iterate throught the column names and at the same time, make value counts for each of it. Sorry, I have always struggled with loops. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, i tried to understand. I added my explaination at the beginning of my awnser. I hope my code worked well for you.

Comment: Yes, I understood what you meant, thank you. Maybe I wasn't clear. "Activity at work" from zero to twenty are columns names, so I dont have one single name for all of them. I have 21 columns, each with very similar names, but same answer for same column, that is why I want to count how many equal answers are for each column, and make them at once. That was my attempt with the loop: iterate for each number in column name, and make value_counts for each.

Comment: Yes i think i understood that, but df['activity'] will return only the column with the exact name activity. And as i see your column names are different. That's why you get the error. Your definition of the variable activity as pandas series has no impact at all. Because 'activity' is interpreted as string not as variable. Nevertheless in this case it's not necessary to hardcode any column names.

Answer (score 0):

You can melt your data and perform value_counts on that:

```
activity_counts= (df.melt(var_name="question", value_name="activity")
                    .value_counts()
                    .reindex(df.columns, level=0)) # preserve the order of question ids

print(activity_counts)
question                   activity
Main activity at work      machine operator    2
Main activity at work .1   administrator       2
Main activity at work .2   accountant          1
Main activity at work .20  cleaning            3
dtype: int64
```

activity_counts is a `pd.Series` with a `pd.MultiIndex` key. If this object is confusing, you can use `.reset_index()` to get it into a more familiar `pd.DataFrame` representation

Comment: Nice solution. I have a question: would I need then to pass all twenty column names ( as a list, I presume) for var_name? "main activity at work" up to twenty are column names. Or is that solved with the reindex part?

Comment: Ah if you have other columns aside from the 20 "main activity at work" columns, you'll need to filter your dataframe before using melt and omit the reindex portion.

Comment: Yes I have many more columns, but I dont think its that important. I think I'm confused about your usage of melt. Your 'question' would be my 20 column names, right? But, how can I use your "activity"? (I mean, how to obtain it for each of the twenty columns). For me, that is precisely the value_counts for each column which I wanted to do in the first place. Sorry to bother you, but I would really like to understand this, since its a recurrent issue in my df.